# Lanczos interpolation in C

Tags: c, image, resampling, lanczos

i need to implement the following formula in c-code:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling
Therefore i'm using the multidimensional interpolation approach:

[image: Multidimensional interpolation]

where L(x-i) or L(y-i) is:

[image: Lanczos Kernel]

I'm using the ppm image format to get rgb values trough a small script.
This is my actual lanczos approach now:

```
double _L(int param) {
    /*
    LANCZOS KERNEL
    */
    
    int a = 2; // factor "a" from formula
    if(param == 0) {
        
        return 1;
    }
    if(abs(param) > 0 && abs(param) < a) {
        
        return (a*sin(PI*param) * sin((PI*param)/a))/(PI*PI*param*param)
    }
    return 0;
}

void lanczos_interpolation(PPMImage *img) {

    if(img) {
        
        int start_i, start_j, limit_i, limit_j;
        int a = 2; // factor "a" from formula
        samples_ij = img->x*img->y; // "sij" from formula
    
        for(x = 0;x < img->x;x++) {
            
            for(y = 0;y = < img->y;y++) {
                
                start_i = floor(x)-a+1:
                limit_i = floor(x)+a;
                for(i = start_i;i <= limit_i;i++) {
                    
                    start_j = floor(y)-a+1:
                    limit_j = floor(y)+a;
                    for(i = start_i;i <= limit_i;i++) {
                        
                        img->data[x+(W*y)].red = (int)(samples_ij * _L(x-i) * _L(y-j)) // "_L" represents "L(x-i)" from formula
                        img->data[x+(W*y)].green = (int)(samples_ij * _L(x-i) * _L(y-j)) // "_L" represents "L(x-i)" from formula
                        img->data[x+(W*y)].blue = (int)(samples_ij * _L(x-i) * _L(y-j)) // "_L" represents "L(x-i)" from formula
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This part of the code confused me a lot:

```
img->data[x+(W*y)].red = (int)(samples_ij * _L(x-i) * _L(y-j)) // "_L" represents "L(x-i)" from formula
img->data[x+(W*y)].green = (int)(samples_ij * _L(x-i) * _L(y-j)) // "_L" represents "L(x-i)" from formula
img->data[x+(W*y)].blue = (int)(samples_ij * _L(x-i) * _L(y-j)) // "_L" represents "L(x-i)" from formula
```

Can someone help me to get along with this lanczos interpolation in c?
Here is my complete C-File:

http://pastebin.com/wdUHVh6U

Thanks!

Comment: I used the Lanczos algorithm during my graduate work, and I think your question might belong better on the math site.  Even if you only have an implementation question, there is a lot of knowledge needed to understand the code fully.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is a programming question, so it is a better fit for SO (this site), IMHO.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Fair enough, I have upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

See you are **not doing any kind of interpolation** in your code.

The interpolation operation is like this:

[`input pixels`] => [`Lanczos interpolation`] => [`output interpolated pixels`]

```
                        |
                        |
                        V
        a sum operation in the neighbourhood 
            of the corresponding location
               in the input image
```

Your problems are the following:

1. You have **not understood** the `Lanczos interpolation technique`. In fact, it seems you don't know **what is interpolation**.
2. Your code does not have the `input pixels` and the `output pixels`.
3. There is no `summation` in your code. (You are just assigning the Lanczos co-efficient times `s_ij` to `img` pixels. Again `s_ij`'s are actually the `input` pixel values in the formula, but you have **assigned a fixed value of total number of pixels in the image** to `s_ij`.)
4. You have unnecessarily used `floor(*)` functions.

My suggestion to you is:

1. **Understand** what is interpolation in an algorithmic way.
2. Write the **algorithm /pseudo-code** for whatever your purpose is.
3. Make sure you are **correct** in Steps 1 and 2.
4. Then only try to **write the code**.